# WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled while starting dcos-vagrant

Tags: vagrant, dcos

I'm new to DC/OS and tried to install dcos-vagrant by following the guide on https://github.com/dcos/dcos-vagrant/blob/master/docs/deploy.md. While running `vagrant up m1 a1 a2 a3 boot` I get the following warnings:

```
==> m1:       WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
==> m1:       WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
```

After the installation I can connect to the webapp on http://m1.dcos and it seems that DC/OS is running. But if I try deploying some applications the nodes cant connect to each other.
Im running dcos-vagrant with:

```
vagrant 1.8.4 
Virtual box 5.0.20
DC/OS 1.8
Mac 10.11, 16 GB RAM
```

Answer (score 1):

Those warnings are normal when using OverlayFS as the Docker volume driver on CentOS 7.

Example `docker info` w/ just Docker: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16127#issuecomment-138400282

They're just warnings, not errors. That's not your problem. You'll need to provide more information about what you mean by "the nodes cant connect to each other" and what kinds of symptoms/logs you're seeing.

You can use `vagrant ssh <node name>` to SSH into nodes, like `m1` for master. Then use `systemd|grep dcos-` to see the DC/OS components and status on that node, and `journalctl -u <unit-name>` to see the component logs. If your nodes can't see each other then the components will be erroring.

If postflight failed by time out, vagrant might unhealpfully destroy the boot node that failed provisioning or maybe the whole cluster. In that case all you have is the vagrant up output, which should give you more info about what failed.