# DC/OS local cluster web gui not accessible

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, mesos, mesosphere, dcos

i wanted to install dc/os on my local machine for development.

i followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/dcos/dcos-vagrant/blob/master/docs/deploy.md)

after calling vagrant up i got warnings:

```
    => m1: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
    ==> m1: Booting VM...
    ==> m1: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
        m1: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
        m1: SSH username: vagrant
        m1: SSH auth method: private key
        m1: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
        m1: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
        m1: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
        m1: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
        m1: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        m1: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
        m1: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
        m1: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
        m1: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
        m1: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...

some ports where in use ?

  m1:       Checking if port 42819 (required by spartan) is in use:
    m1:       PASS
    m1:       Checking if port 43911 (required by minuteman) is in use:
    m1:       PASS
    m1:       Checking if port 46839 (required by metronome) is in use:
    m1:       PASS
    m1:       Checking if port 61053 (required by mesos-dns) is in use:
    m1:       PASS
    m1:       Checking if port 61420 (required by epmd) is in use:
    m1:       PASS
    m1:       Checking if port 61421 (required by minuteman) is in use:
    m1:       PASS
    m1:       Checking if port 62053 (required by spartan) is in use:
    m1:       PASS
    m1:       Checking if port 62080 (required by navstar) is in use:
    m1:       PASS
```

and at the end again two WARNINGS EDIT:  they should not be the problem [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39797602/warning-bridge-nf-call-iptables-is-disabled-while-starting-dcos-vagrant#)

```
  p1:       PASS
    p1:       Checking Docker is configured with a production storage driver:
    a1:       Creating role file for slave
==> p1:       WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
==> p1:       WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
    a1:       Configuring DC/OS
    p1:       PASS (overlay)
    p1:       Creating directories under /etc/mesosphere
    a1:       Setting and starting DC/OS
    p1:       Creating role file for slave_public
    p1:       Configuring DC/OS
    p1:       Setting and starting DC/OS
==> p1:       Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dcos-setup.service to /etc/systemd/system/dcos-setup.service.
==> a1:       Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dcos-setup.service to /etc/systemd/system/dcos-setup.service.
==> m1: DC/OS Postflight
==> a1: DC/OS Postflight
==> p1: DC/OS Postflight
==> m1: [sudo]$ dcos-postflight
==> a1: [sudo]$ dcos-postflight
==> p1: [sudo]$ dcos-postflight
==> a1: Setting Mesos Memory: 5632 (role=*)
==> a1: [sudo]$ mesos-memory 5632
    a1:       Updating /var/lib/dcos/mesos-resources
==> a1: Restarting Mesos Agent
==> a1: [sudo]$ bash -ceu "systemctl stop dcos-mesos-slave.service && rm -f /var/lib/mesos/slave/meta/slaves/latest && systemctl start dcos-mesos-slave.service --no-block"
==> p1: Setting Mesos Memory: 1024 (role=slave_public)
==> p1: [sudo]$ mesos-memory 1024 slave_public
    p1:       Updating /var/lib/dcos/mesos-resources
==> p1: Restarting Mesos Agent
==> p1: [sudo]$ bash -ceu "systemctl stop dcos-mesos-slave-public.service && rm -f /var/lib/mesos/slave/meta/slaves/latest && systemctl start dcos-mesos-slave-public.service --no-block"
==> boot: DC/OS Installation Complete
==> boot: Web Interface: http://m1.dcos/
```

I just followed the instution on Github, and installed virtualbox and vagrant on Windows 10.

why cant i access the web ui at http://m1.dcos ? What are the warnings?

Comment: did you update your host file ?

Comment: yes, i solved my problem now. I just installed verything again and now it works :S. Still dont know what caused the problem. Thx